# Stand alone method is calling another method by itself

Tags: ruby, learn-ruby-the-hard-way

Ok i seriously suck at passing method to methods whenever i want to return something from the method. Can you guys explain on how do i go about passing it.
Here's my hash

```
$choosen_gun = {}
$Weapon = {
    :Bazoka => ["Bazoka",5],
    :Machine_gun => ["Machine_gun",1000],
    :Hand_gun => ["Hand_gun",24,2],
    :Double_Hand_gun => ["Double_Hand_gun",24,4],
    :Sniper => ["Sniper",12,1],
    :Shot_gun => ["Shot_gun",8,2]
}
```

Here's my code for method  Weapon

```
    def Weapon
        puts "Now it's time to select your weapon."
        puts "Please choose a weapon that is good throughout the game."
        puts "Whenever you are shortage of bullets, please reload it."
        puts "Please avoid last minute of reloading of weapon."
        puts "Now choose your weapon based on your own preferences."
        print  "\n"

        puts "Type 1"
        puts "Gun Name: Bazoka"
        puts "Description: A powerful gun that is strong with only 5 bullets."
        puts "Rating: ★ ★ ★ ★"
        num = gets.chomp.to_i

       case num 
          when 1 
          puts "Selection of Bazoka is chosen"
          puts "Loaded 5 bullets only"
          $choosen_gun[num] = $Weapon[:Bazoka]
       end      
     return num
end
```

Upon calling the method. The user will choose his weapon and it will add it to the $choosen_gun hash with it's num, and it's return it's num what the user types

Here's my code for method  ZombieRoom

```
    def ZombieRoom(w)
    zombie = {
        :Construcied => [5],
        :Invader => [5],
        :Damned => [5],
        :Steampunk => [5],
        :Stoner => [5],
        :Wasted => [5],
        :Romero => [5]
    }
             puts "Welcome to the worst night mare of Zombie Room"
             puts "You will be fighting with a random zombie"


             while true 
             puts ".........."
             puts "Selecting a random zombie"
             puts "Selecting your prefered gun...."
             case w 
                   when 1 
                   $choosen_gun[1]
                   puts "Your selected gun is #{$choosen_gun[1][0]}"
                   #values = zombie.values
                   #puts values[rand(values.size)]
                   #random_zombie = zombie.keys.sample(1)
                   #puts random_zombie[   
                    random_zombie = zombie.to_a.sample(1).to_h
                    random_zombie.each do |key,value|
                    puts "Your random zombie is #{key}"
                    puts "With a health value of #{value[0]}"


                    puts "Time to take down that zombie now."
                    while true
                    puts "Type Shoot to knock it down or quit."
                    choice = gets.chomp
                    if $choosen_gun[1][1] >= 1
                        health = value[0] -= 1
                        $choosen_gun[1][1] -= 1 
                    puts "#{key} health now is #{health}"
                    else
                    puts "Please reload your gun"
                    puts "Reloading......"
                    $choosen_gun[1][1] += 5  
                    end 

                    if health == 0 
                        puts "You have defeated #{key}"
                        puts "Congrats!!!"
                        puts "We are happy for you"
                        puts "Lets begins to collect your prize"
                         CollectPrize()
                     else
                        puts "You did not defeat the #{key} yet"
                    end

                    end

                    end
       end
     end
   end
```

Here's my code for method  CollectPrize

```
def CollectPrize
      puts "Congratulations on defeating"
      puts "We would now like to give you some case prizes"

      print "\n"

      puts "Please choose only 1 prize for yourself"
      print "\n"
      puts "Type 1"
      puts "$50,000"
      print "\n"
      puts "Type 2"
      puts "$25,000"
      print "\n"
      puts "Type 3"
      puts "$55,000"
      hoho = gets.chomp.to_f


      if hoho == 1
            puts "hehe"
      end
end
```

Here how i call my method

```
ZombieRoom(Weapon())
CollectPrize()
```

Now the problem is that whenever the CollectPrize method is called and i type my input to collect the prize example 1 then it print "$50,000". instead of the ending the problem, it went back to the ZombieRoom and continues to loop at the "Type Shoot to knock it down or quit." Can someone atleast tell me a proper way to solve this issue or also what other way to pass a method?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does "passing method to methods" mean? From what I can see, you never pass a method to a method anywhere, so why is that relevant? Why do you need to do that "whenever i want to return something from the method"? What does the "it" in "Can you guys explain on how do i go about passing it." refer to? Also, please provide a [mcve], and pay special attention to the "M" (Minimal) part. I highly doubt that you need 120 lines of code to replicate your problem. In fact, I have spotted several bugs that are completely unrelated to your problem, but make it pretty much …

Comment: … impossible to diagnose.

Comment: Read the last statement and you will understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is in a large `while true` loop.  Since true is always true, it will never end, so after it calls CollectPrize() it just goes back to the `while` statement.

You could get out of it by inserting a `break` line after the `CollectPrize()` but there's another `while true` loop around this one.

I think you need to pay closer attention to how you want to exit the while loops.

```
puts "Time to take down that zombie now."
while true # <---------------- this is ALWAYS going to loop, without end
  puts "Type Shoot to knock it down or quit."
  choice = gets.chomp
  if $choosen_gun[1][1] >= 1
    health = value[0] -= 1
    $choosen_gun[1][1] -= 1 
    puts "#{key} health now is #{health}"
  else
    puts "Please reload your gun"
    puts "Reloading......"
    $choosen_gun[1][1] += 5  
  end 
  if health == 0 
    puts "You have defeated #{key}"
    puts "Congrats!!!"
    puts "We are happy for you"
    puts "Lets begins to collect your prize"
    CollectPrize()
  else
    puts "You did not defeat the #{key} yet"
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok thank you. It's my mistake that i didn't check the CollectPrize method is at zombie_room method. That's why it's keep looping.

Comment: No problem, if you found my answer helpful feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

In ruby constants start with Capital letter. 
Methods are always defined in lower case.

Try this in irb

```
irb(main):001:0> def Weapon
irb(main):002:1> end
=> :Weapon
irb(main):003:0> Weapon
NameError: uninitialized constant Weapon
```

To solve your problem name methods using ruby's naming conventions:
`zombie_room`, `collect_prize` etc.

Then this code will work:
`zombie_room(weapon())`

What you are doing there is not really passing method weapon to method zombie room. 
What is really going on is that method weapon is executed, then it returns a value and result of that value is passed to method zombie_room.

I think that is what you wanted.

If you need to pass a method, check out documentation for `proc` and `lambda` or just use blocks.

Comment: This isn't strictly correct.  if you do `def Weapon` and `end` and `Weapon` you'll see the `uninitialized constant` error.  But if you explicity call it *as* a method, with parentheses... `Weapon()` as the OP does, then it will work. That's not to say it's good practice, but it's not the cause of OP's issue.

Comment: Good point. I am still going to leave this as answer because he might learn from it.

Comment: Thank you guys. :)

Comment: I think you should have accepted the other answer cause it was better. You can upvote answer (up arrow above number 0) if you like it.